# Matlb: Plot of differential equation solution does not change if i change initial parameters

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new in matlab, and i am stuck in a problem that i have to solve before 29-12 !

I have the code that correctly solves a differential equation and plot the solution in a graph in which i have space vs time, now i am interested in what changes if i change the 2 initial parameters values but when i change them and solve again, the graph does not change at all, even if i setup big values of the parameters.

Here i show the code for the solver:

```
clear all;  
close all;  
clc;  

T11=0;  
dtode=0.001;  
TNt=100;  

R0=0.1;  
init=R0;  
[T,R] = ode23(@faili1,T11:dtode:TNt,init);  
Ntode=lenght(T);  

r=R(1:1:Ntode,1);  

plot(T,r)
```

Comment: It would be much easier for us to look at this if you put the code into your question rather than display it as two screenshots.

Comment: what is `faili1`?

Comment: It's the function where i defined the differential equation and the datas

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: the new values i was trying to enter for parameters were out of range and did not display any error massage.